# Find the intersect area of two overlapping rectangles

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm, interview-questions, collision

This is my solution to find the coordinates of 2 overlapped rectangles implemented in JavaScript. Each rectangle is represented by 2 points, each with 2 (x,y) coordinates.

[image: Cases of overlapped rectangles]
Can this code be improved?

```
const maxOfX = (rec) => (Math.max(rec.x1, rec.x2));
const maxOfY = (rec) => (Math.max(rec.y1, rec.y2));
const minOfX = (rec) => (Math.min(rec.x1, rec.x2));
const minOfY = (rec) => (Math.min(rec.y1, rec.y2));
const comBinedRectangle = (rec1, rec2) => {
  let overlappedRec = {};
  const NolappingFromX = maxOfX(rec1) <= minOfX(rec2) || minOfX(rec1) >= maxOfX(rec2);
  const NolappingFromY = maxOfY(rec1) <= minOfY(rec2) || minOfY(rec1) >= maxOfY(rec2);
  if (!(NolappingFromX || NolappingFromY)) {
    overlappedRec.x1 = Math.max(minOfX(rec1), minOfX(rec2));
    overlappedRec.y1 = Math.max(minOfY(rec1), minOfY(rec2));
    overlappedRec.x2 = Math.min(maxOfX(rec1), maxOfX(rec2));
    overlappedRec.y2 = Math.min(maxOfY(rec1), maxOfY(rec2));
  }

  return overlappedRec;
}
const rectangle1 = { x1: 2, y1: 2, x2: 4, y2: 4 };
const rectangle2 = { x1: 3, y1: 3, x2: 6, y2: 2 };
console.log(comBinedRectangle(rectangle1, rectangle2));
// { x1: 3, y1: 2, x2: 4, y2: 3 }
```

Comment: Don't write, never present undocumented/uncommented code. Don't do `(boolean expression) ? true : false`. Try to limit line length.

Comment: Are you talking about combination, intersection or even bounding rectangles? Why put 'overlapping' in the name when non-intersecting rectangles are equally valid input?

Comment: Why not create a Rectange class? I did something similar whilst working on a visualisation project and it helped make sense of the code e.g. `rect1.intersects(rect2)`

Answer (score 3):

```js
/**
 * Returns intersecting part of two rectangles
 * @param  {object}  r1 4 coordinates in form of {x1, y1, x2, y2} object
 * @param  {object}  r2 4 coordinates in form of {x1, y1, x2, y2} object
 * @return {boolean}    False if there's no intersecting part
 * @return {object}     4 coordinates in form of {x1, y1, x2, y2} object
 */
const getIntersectingRectangle = (r1, r2) => {  
  [r1, r2] = [r1, r2].map(r => {
    return {
      x: [r.x1, r.x2].sort((a,b) => a - b),
      y: [r.y1, r.y2].sort((a,b) => a - b)
    };
  });

  const noIntersect = r2.x[0] > r1.x[1] || r2.x[1] < r1.x[0] ||
                      r2.y[0] > r1.y[1] || r2.y[1] < r1.y[0];

  return noIntersect ? false : {
    x1: Math.max(r1.x[0], r2.x[0]), // _[0] is the lesser,
    y1: Math.max(r1.y[0], r2.y[0]), // _[1] is the greater
    x2: Math.min(r1.x[1], r2.x[1]),
    y2: Math.min(r1.y[1], r2.y[1])
  };
};

/*  ↓  DEMO  ↓  */

const rectangle1 = { x1: 2, y1: 2, x2: 4, y2: 4 };
const rectangle2 = { x1: 3, y1: 3, x2: 6, y2: 2 };

console.log(getIntersectingRectangle(rectangle1, rectangle2));
// { x1: 3, y1: 2, x2: 4, y2: 3 }
```

First, both rectangles get transformed into object with keys `x` and `y` and sorted arrays of two of corresponding them coordinates as values.

```
r1 = {
  x: [2, 4], // x1, x2
  y: [2, 4]  // y1, y2
}
r2 = {
  x: [3, 6], // x1, x2
  y: [2, 3]  // Y2, Y1 !
}
```

That's because for this job it is important to know which of `x`s and `y`s is lesser and which is greater. Rather than `Math.max()` and `Math.min()` a single `.sort()` can be used.

Alternative would be to declare that `(x1, y1)` is assumed to always be top-left corner, but as I see in `rectangle2` in your question, that is apparently not always the case.

Now, `noIntersect` is negated

```
!(a.left > b.right || b.left > a.right || a.top > b.bottom || b.top > a.bottom);
```

which tests if in both axes sides from one end of one figure exceed opposite-direction end side of the other figure, e.g. if left side of figure `a` is more to the right than the right side of figure `b`.

At the end we return false if there is no intersection of our rectangles, or an object with coordinates if there is. Intersecting part will always span from:

the greater of the 2 lesser `x`s of both rectangles

to

the lesser of the 2 greater `x`s of both rectangles.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the JS array.sort() functions sort values as strings, thus this will yield incorrect results (try: getIntersectingRectangle({x1: 420, y1: 5, x2: 509, y2: 36},{x1: 432, y1: 18, x2: 450, y2: 30}) ).  You can fix the sort function by providing a comperator e.g. points.sort((a,b) => a - b)

Comment: @BenBracha
Thank you so much for your comment.
I encountered this exact bug and I would have never figured that out (working sometimes but sometimes not because number of digits was different).
The answer should not be accepted with this bug.

Comment: @BenBracha Thanks, I missed that one! The answer was corrected.

Answer (score 1):

- Document/comment
  I have no idea whether there are agreed standards for ECMAScript, e.g. [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/about-getting-started.html#adding-documentation-comments-to-your-code).
- *If* I used what you called `OverX` I'd call it `OverlapX` and invert it.
  `OverlapX = minOfX(rec1) <= maxOfX(rec2) && minOfX(rec2) <= maxOfX(rec1);`
- precomputing booleans the way of `OverX` and `OverY` precludes short-circuiting the evaluation of the combined *no-overlap-condition*.
- One *could* use "nomalised" rects: `minx`/`miny`/`maxx`/`maxy`.
- (*I'd prefer* plain function definitions over arrow functions if they are going to get a name, anyway.)
- (There is bound to be a way to have, e.g. `Math.min(values)` operate on all x-coordinates of a shape, my ignorance thereof notwithstanding.)